# Why i cant take user id from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following method in DatabaseHelper Class

```
 /**
 * This method is to fetch user id after login or register
 */


public int GetUserID(String tableName,String emailId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+emailId+"%'";
    Cursor c = db.query(true, tableName, null,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c.getCount()>0)
        return c.getInt(0);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

When i m trying to use in another activity as

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            int usr_id = String.valueOf(databaseHelper.GetUserID(databaseHelper.TABLE_USER,textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
```

I cant have access to TABLE_USER cause is private in Datahelper Class. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :-

```
public int GetUserID(String tableName,String emailId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+emailId+"%'";
    Cursor c = db.query(true, tableName, null,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c.getCount()>0)
        return c.getInt(0);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

to be

```
public int GetUserID(String emailId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    String where = COLUMN_USER_EMAIL+" LIKE '%"+String.valueOf(emailId)+"%'";
    Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE_USER, null,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(c.getCount()>0)
        return c.getInt(0);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

and also change

```
int usr_id = String.valueOf(databaseHelper.GetUserID(databaseHelper.TABLE_USER,textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
```

to be :-

```
int usr_id = String.valueOf(databaseHelper.GetUserID(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()));
```

This solution codes the table name in the DatabaseHelper class. There appears to be no reason, from what you have provided to pass a constant value.

Alternately change

```
private static final TABLE_USER = .........
```

to

```
public static final TABLE_USER = .........
```

*(where .......... represents the rest of the code that hasn't been provided).*

This solution simply makes the TABLE_USER variable visible outside of the DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: For some reason now i cant take the user Id as int but only as String. Any idea? Actually i took it from a working code and checked that the TABLE_USER was private there too.

Comment: Answer changed.